# Using VW units on Android stock browser v4.4.2

Tags: android, css, samsung-mobile

As far as I can tell this *should* be supported, but my test phone won't use the value.  The OS version on the phone is 4.4.2 (it's a Samsung S3).  Am I missing something?

It's very basic CSS:

```
.elem {height: 13vw;)
.elem h4 {font-size:3.4vw;}
.elem h5 {font-size:2.7vw;}
```

etc.

Comment: Not as far as it is possible to tell from the little information we have. As you say, it *should* work but perhaps that something Samsung have messed with.

Comment: I know my post is sparse on details, but there isn't much I can say other than the software version and the CSS attribute I'm trying use use.  I can't help thinking I'm missing something simple, maybe a meta tag, but those are factory issue too...


    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

Comment: I certainly wouldn't use `maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"`...some people need to zoom/scale..but I doubt it's related.

Comment: Up untill 4.3 this wasn't supported (http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units), so it's possible your phone got shipped with an older version of the browser.